# Reduce this lambda Expression

Tags: lambda-calculus

(λy.λy.yy)(yy)
Guys, I am unable to solve this expression.
I would appreciate it if someone helps me solve this lambda expression with stepwise reduction

Comment: @Jorge Adriano, could you pls help me out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(λy.λy.yy)(yy)
```

The first lambda never "gets to use" its variable because it's named the same as the inner lambda. Nevertheless, if this isn't a transcription error, the reduction is straightforward.

Before you reduce an expression where there could be a name conflict, rename the bound variables. The expression becomes:

```
(λx.λz.zz)(yy)
```

Next, substitute.
Since variable x from the first lambda doesn't have any bound instance to replace, anything you apply to it gets discarded.

```
λz.zz
```

Since this expression cannot be reduced more, this is the normal form.